# MongoDB merging an object element to another element from aggregate

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

So currently I have this object right now

```json
{
  "notifications": [
    {
      "author": "5862184743205863247",
      "type": "friend",
      "value": "5862184743205863247",
      "avatar": "https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/avataaars/ZAZA.png",
      "id": "5861675623319076687",
      "createdAt": "2022-03-24T13:43:06.637Z",
      "status": "Hello! I just joined unchat!",
      "username": "ZAZA"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I merge the `username, status, createdAt, id` to the `author` element. So the result would be

```json
 {
  "notifications": [
    {
      "author": {
        "avatar": "https://avatars.dicebear.com/api/avataaars/ZAZA.png",
        "id": "5861675623319076687",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-24T13:43:06.637Z",
        "status": "Hello! I just joined unchat!",
        "username": "ZAZA"
      },
      "type": "friend",
      "value": "5862184743205863247"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the code I am using right now, I used a lookup to get the other author objects like the username or the id

https://sourceb.in/aUjZQ5DJU9

- Sorry I put it in sourcebin because it was long and I didn't wnat the form to be messy

Comment: Why are you using the `$filter` within the `$map`?

Comment: @prasad_ I don't know, I got this code from another so question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      notifications: {
        $map: {
          input: "$notifications",
          as: "n",
          in: {
            author: {
              avatar: "$$n.avatar",
              id: "$$n.id",
              createdAt: "$$n.createdAt",
              status: "$$n.status",
              username: "$$n.username"
            },
            type: "$$n.type",
            value: "$$n.value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ss58LfeniJT)